# Spring Security SAML SSO - Global logout

Tags: spring, security, global, logout, saml-2.0

I am looking for documentation of the Global architecture logout, I have reviewed some links but I have a scenario that I can not find.
What happens if the local session of an SP expires? I did a lab and I noticed that when a TimeOut of the local session occurs, the security context is lost. In this architecture the local session timeOut should not expire(SPs)?

If you have any documentation links for this scenario, thank them infinitely!!

Answer (score 0):

In SAMLv2 there is no real concept for session correlation. SAML assertions issued by the IdP do have a validity set (condition attributes "NotBefore" and "NotOnOrAfter" which must be checked by the SP). Actually the SP should query the IdP before the assertion times out (using a so called "passive AuthnRequest") to check whether the session at the IdP is still valid.

Some IdP implementation have proprietary extensions to notify the SP when the IdP session times out, however this mostly requires SOAP binding being supported by the SPs as it's happening 'out-of-band' (without user-agent interaction).

Workaround for your issue .... the (idle) timeout of the local session must be higher than on the IdP.